# accepts_nested_attributes_for values cleared when validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have the following relationships

```
class user
 has_many cars
 has_many journeys, :through => :cars
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :journeys
end

class car
 belongs_to user
 belongs_to journey
end

class journey
 has_many car
 has_many users, :through => :cars
end
```

I have a form to **edit** of both an existing user and/or journey:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, :url => edit_user_path(@user), :method => :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :email %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :journey, @journey do |j| %>
     <%= f.input_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have a validation on the @user.email attribute. If this fails it returns the form correctly with all the @user attributes present. However, it clears any value I might have put in the @journey.name attribute input field.

This isn't very user friendly as the user obviously has already filled this field in. How do I stop this from happening?

**EDIT: Updated with an answer based on the information below**

In the end I passed settled on the following. The `:journeys` provided me with the requisite rails functionality to repopulate the form correctly on a validation error and the if statement ensured it only ever displayed the required instance:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, :url => edit_user_path(@user), :method => :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :email %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :journeys do |j| %>
     <% if @journey.id == j.object.id %>
        <%= f.input_field :name %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify the `@journey` on your simple_fields_for - that's not the instance you're validating and repopulating. Let Rails handle it - it will pick `@user.journeys` for you.

Comment: Yes, but I'm **editing** a specific ```@journey``` that the ```@user``` owns. If I remove that it'll just give me an input field that will create a new instance of ```@user.journeys``` won't it?

Comment: ...and the answer is no it won't! Wow, Rails continues to amaze me with it's intelligence. How does it know I'm dealing with that @journey specifically?

Comment: it'll just iterate over whatever's in `@user.journeys`. If there's a new empty record in there, then you'll get a blank set of form fields; if there are some saved instances in there, you'll get one set of fields for each instance. Rails can be pretty clever.

Comment: ah, but now I have a problem. If I go back in having created a new journey and hit the same form it's now showing me the details for both journeys. I only want the most recent one. Any ideas?